# Facebook SDK getAccessToken() problems

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, access-token

I have been having some trouble with the facebook SDK, specifically retrieving an access token. The App is set up on Facebook correctly and has been given permission. As far as I can tell, the code is correct and I am not sure what is going wrong with getAccessToken().

**$facebook->getAccessToken();** is returning *"12345678|abcdefghijklmnop"*, basically some kind of variable which is made up of the App ID and Secret ID separated by a |

**$facebook->getUser();** is returning '*0*'

```
<?php
     require_once("facebook.php"); //Up-to-date SDK files from Git

     $app_id = "12345678"; //replaced with fake
     $app_secret = "abcdefghijklmnop"; //replaced with fake

     $facebook = new Facebook(array(
         'appId' => $app_id,
         'secret' => $app_secret,
         'cookie' => true; //I have tried 'false' here as well
     ));

     $token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Facebook SDK:

```
  public function getAccessToken() {
    if ($this->accessToken !== null) {
      return $this->accessToken;
    }

    $this->setAccessToken($this->getApplicationAccessToken());
    $user_access_token = $this->getUserAccessToken();
    if ($user_access_token) {
      $this->setAccessToken($user_access_token);
    }

    return $this->accessToken;
  }

  protected function getApplicationAccessToken() {
    return $this->appId.'|'.$this->appSecret;
  }
```

Your access token will be `APP ID|APP SECRET` which is the application token, or `A RANDOM TOKEN HERE`, which is the user access token, when you have a user signed:

```
$facebook->getUser();
```

When `getUser()` return `0` (which is same as `false`, and user not signed) you need to request a login, and authorization (if have not authorized yet) for your application:

```
if (!$facebook->getUser())
{
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'scope' => 'publish_stream' // Permissions goes here
        ) 
    );
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        top.location.href = " <?php echo $login_url; ?>";
    </script>
<?php
    exit;
}
```

see available permissions types here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Comment: Thanks! I learned stuff! I'll explain a bit about what I'm trying to do though.

I'm trying to fetch the most recent note from the Notes section of a Facebook page and display it on a website for anyone who goes there. Does every user who goes to the third party website have to have facebook account and have to log in to it to see the note?

I had this whole thing working for 30 seconds and then I obviously changed something and it stopped working but the undo button didn't fix it :) I believe that's when it also started giving APP ID|APP SECRET instead. Then I made the original post here.

Comment: If `Notes` are public, you don't need user login. See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/note/

Comment: Need to request from `$facebook->api('IDOFPAGE/notes');` (can't find the documentation for this, but, probably, this is the correct way)

Comment: Yes, thanks! I guess not having the Facebook page published yet is the problem. Always learning :) Have a nice day!

Comment: Yep, you need the page published.

Answer (score 2):

`$facebook->getAccessToken();` is returning `"12345678|abcdefghijklmnop"`, basically some kind of variable which is made up of the App ID and Secret ID separated by a |