# Facebook PHP SDK: getAccessToken not correct on refresh

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-oauth

On my facebook app, I'm logging a user in using the Javascript SDK.
If OK, I redirect him to this PHP page (designed to illustrate my problem):

test.php:

```
<?php
include('config.php');
require('phpsdk.php');

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
echo $access_token;
echo "<br /><br />";
$user = $facebook->getUser();
echo $user;
?>
```

(phpsdk.php handels the PHP SDK initiation)

Accessing test.php the FIRST time, returns a valid access token and the ID of the logged user.
However, when I refresh the page, the access token becomes of the type [appID|appSecret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705363/facebook-sdk-getaccesstoken-problems).
The user is still logged in: getUser still returns the correct user ID.

Anyone knows what's causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended to call `getAccessToken();` over and over the way you described.

You should try first to see if the token is in the browser as a session and if not then try to use the `SDK` to find or request it.

1. Check browser for a user, if no user call sdk for user, if still null or 0 auth or reauth.
2. If user, check browser for access_token, if no token call sdk for token.

---

```
<?php
session_start();
include('config.php');
require('phpsdk.php');
    // need to replace Your_App_ID and YourAppId with your applications id. 
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => 'Your_App_ID',
        'secret' => 'Your_App_Secret',
        'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
    ));    
    if(isset($_SESSION['fb_YourAppId_user_id'])){
        $user = $_SESSION['fb_YourAppId_user_id'];  
    }else{
        $user = $facebook->getUser();
    }
    if($user){
        if(isset($_SESSION['fb_YourAppId_access_token'])){
            $access_token = $_SESSION['fb_YourAppId_access_token'];
        }else{
            $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
        }
    }   
echo $user;
echo "<br /><br />";
echo $access_token;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can see how it's good practice to first check the sessions. I've added `print_r($_SESSION);` to test.php to check for them. I've noticed that, on refresh, `$_SESSION['fb_YourAppId_access_token']` gets unset as well, which means the php SDK is using a a wrong token. `$facebook->api("/me"); ` result (AFTER refresh) in an AccessToken error. It's, off course, not only on refresh. The major problem is, when I link to other pages, the access token gets lost, so I can't extract any user data on other pages.

Comment: One solution would be to put the access_token (the first time,before refresh) in a session you create yourself, and then use `$facebook->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);` on pages where you want to extract user data. Another solution would be to put all the user data in sessions right after authorization (before refresh). Although both solution should work, I'm really suprised seeing this behaviour. Why does the access_token disappear? And what solution should I use?

Comment: I've found that, when I put this on test.php (=the page the script redirect to after login), the described problem is happening (no access token after refresh):

`$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
echo $access_token;
$user = $facebook->getUser();`

However, when I put:
`$user = $facebook->getUser();
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
echo $access_token;`

The problem does not appear...

Comment: Ya on redirect you get a code in the url, the access token is then based on that code, if you just use the api to get your token then the code should be in array and used for token each refresh.

Comment: Notice that if you do not use the redirect, the code in session changes on every refresh, this is required and why your url code was failing.

Comment: i would suggest to you to wrap your getaccesstoken() call in a user argument.  The reason for this is if no user is detected it will not try to call for access token anyway and will stop any errors or failures from doing that.

if($user){  }

Comment: You will also need to set up a method for delete these sessions using the sdk when the user logs out, or they will persist. I will post a seperate answer with a sample.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? Both situations (the failing one and the working one) are done using a redirect. The only difference is that in the working example `getUser();`is on top. In the failing example, `getAccessToken` is on top.

Comment: Thanks! Looking forward for the sample.

Comment: You can not have an access_token with out a user, so you should also call to see if there is a user first, see my first example for the order.

Comment: So, you HAVE to check for a user, before you can get an access token? Even if there is a logged user, but you did not check for it, you won't get your access token?

Comment: You can call only the access token and it will work most of the time and fail when there is no user, the error free way is to call user first, if($user){ call token here }  so you only try the token if there is a user and get no errors.  "unless expired and you make an api call."

Comment: Mine just failed 100% of the time then :). No worries, it works now! Which is a great relieve. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to also look into using the sdk to debug your access tokens so you know when they are going to expire, and can reauth users accordingly.  Personally i use java-script sdk to do my re-auth, but it is possible using php.

Comment: I'll look into that, thanks. Now I just have script that checks if they are still valid. If not, they are redirected to the login page again to get a now, valid one.

Comment: P.s.: the fix for this problem seems to fix my other problem too... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741646/delay-between-login-javascript-sdk-and-access-token-php-sdk

I'll test it a bit more next week and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

**Clearing the Facebook Session with php sdk in redirect when user logs out.**

*Logout.php redirect user and use sdk to clear session data.*

example redirect url.  `yourdomain.com/Logout.php?destroy=true`

refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-destroySession/

---

```
<?php
session_start();
require './src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'appID',
  'secret' => 'appSecret',
  'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
  ));
 if(isset($_GET['destroy'])){
   $facebook->destroySession(); 
 }
?>
```

Comment: I have all these functions running and ready on my index.php but it may be easier for the sake of learning if you seperate them into Login.php / Logout.php / and ApiCall.php "for any api calls you need to test."